# django python if statement

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a basic if statement in Django. I want to display a banner

```
model.py
class Banner(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    banner_img = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

view.py
class BannerView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'website/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_banners'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Banner.objects.all()

index.html
{% if all_banners %}
  {% for banner in all_banners %}
    <img src="{{ banner.banner_img.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h3>You don't have any banner</h3>
{% endif %}
```

basically I need to display banner.
I did upload the banner from admin page. I get the output else statement
Please, advise me.

Comment: Did you set the media urls (in the root `urls.py`)?

Comment: yes i did path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

Comment: that is the url for your *view*, but you need to use Django's views to serve static/media files.

Comment: @absalam48 you say `path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index')` but your view is named `BannerView`?

Comment: if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i want to display index page. thats why i mention IndexView

Comment: @absalam48 Do you have adBlocker in your browser? 
I was implement your code exactly and worked without any error. my template coed enter in if statement and at the first try doesn't load image after disable adBlocker worked completely true

Comment: @absalam48 please edit your question and upload your urls.py file

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a method in your view.py instead of a class.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def banner_view(request):
    all_banners = Banner.objects.all()
    return render('website/index.html',{'all_banners':all_banners})
```

In your urls.py, you'll have to put:

```
from [app name] import views
from django.urls import path

urlpattens = [
    path('', views.[app name], name="[whichever name you want to give it]"),
]
```